# AWS Cloud Formation WordPress URL Times Out

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

My WordPress URL times out. I think there is a problem with the key pair. I am using the book AWS certified cloud practitioner complete training while playing with AWS. This book does not provide information on any errors. I created a key pair with these instructions https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-key-pairs.html#having-ec2-create-your-key-pair. The cloudformation manager output contains a URL because the previous processes were successful. The URL times out, saying check your connection.

Comment: I can provide more information. What do you suggest? giving this a -1 rating is not resourceful. Useful information and instructions or a credited blog would be a better use of your and my time!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I misunderstood what you did or what you're trying to achieve. Following the link you posted what you're doing there is creating a key pair to login to your EC2 instance via SSH, that's not an ssl certificate, with that key pair you can `ssh ec2-user@your_ec2_dns_name -i the_key_you_created` but that won't affect your ability to access your WordPress site via browser. It looks to me like the problem is in your WordPress configuration. Have you checked that your WP home and WP siteurl (under Settings->General) have the correct value (the url that you're trying to access via browser), a good way to test this without meddling directly with the database is modifying your wp-config.php and adding :
`define('WP_HOME','http://example.com'); define('WP_SITEURL','http://example.com');`

That will probably solve it

Answer (score 0):

You get timeout when using key-pair to remote to EC2 or when accessing to wordpress site by browser?

I think you should check opened ports of security group. In order to remote over SSH, you should add port 22 with your IP.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-network-security.html

Comment: I get timeout when accessing WordPress by browser. i see this link, and i will drive into the article thx!

Comment: you should add port 80 and 443 for anyip 0.0.0.0